# Authorize filter remembered?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I had a following controller:

```
[Authorize]
public class MyController: Controller 
{
}
```

When I removed `[Authorize]` application still forces me to log-in in order to access action. Why?

Comment: Do you build after removing ?

Comment: Of course - like always.

Comment: Does your `Action` contain `[Authorize]`?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao of course no. I have also tried to add `AllowAnonymousAttribute` but no luck. Maybe IIS loads old dll?

Comment: Try stopping `IIS`, Restarting VS.. Cos this seems `wiered` behavior.. Otherwise, check if you have any custom `authorization` written and also check your `web.config` file for any suspicious setting.

Comment: Ah.... busted! It turned out that some weirdo put authorized child action in layout view... So that is why authorization was still required -_-.. Git blame!